# circular reference between Spring Security and org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig when upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, springdoc

When upgrading my application from Spring Boot 2.5 to 2.6, I am getting this error :

> Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0;
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
> parameter 0;
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
> 'swaggerIndexTransformer';
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig':
> Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable
> circular reference?

This error is documented on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default and I know I could "fix" it by setting  a property and go back to Spring Boot 2.5 behavior.. But if I can take the opportunity to fix a circular reference, I may as well do it for the future.

My `securityConfig` is simple, because my application is a public application returning some html content, to all callers, with no authentication. so this is my config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
    //application is open to everyone - no security
    security.httpBasic().disable();
  }
}
```

the `setContentNegotationStrategy` that the error mentions is a method from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that I am not overriding, so I am not able to understand what I need to do.

if I delete my `SecurityConfig` class, then I still have an error, same as before but without the mention of my `SecurityConfig` class:

> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
> parameter 0;
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
> 'swaggerIndexTransformer';
>
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig':
> Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable
> circular reference?

what is the recommended way to deal with what seems to be a circular reference between Spring Security and org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem's caused by `org.springdoc.ui.SwaggerConfig`. It has been fixed by [these changes](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/commit/b12677973565527d9be86424ca080be08bde1716#diff-9133f2052d9674095517c9847808f479ddb9fcc5027e6df5739521b802583c4b) which are available in [springdocs-openapi 1.5.13](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/releases/tag/v1.5.13).